Not able to record voice and convert to speech using react-native-tab-view and react-native-voice/voice
const ApptSummary: React.FC\<Props\> = ({ navigation }): JSX.Element =\> {

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

const renderScene = SceneMap({
    third: () => <ApptPrediagnosisNotes isActive={index === 0} />,
    fourth: () => <PhysicianDiagnosis isActive={index === 1} />,
});

const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'third', title: 'Pre-Diagnosis' },
    { key: 'fourth', title: 'Physician Diagnosis' },
]);

const renderTabBar = props => (
    <TabBar
        {...props}
        scrollEnabled
        indicatorStyle={{
            backgroundColor: colors.primary
        }}
        style={{
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
        }}
        tabStyle={{
            padding: 0, // Set padding to 0 to remove any default padding
            //margin: 2, // Set the margin to create spacing between tabs
            width: 110,
        }}
        renderLabel={({ route, focused, color }) => (
            <Text style={[{ color: focused ? colors.black : 'gray', fontSize: 14 }]}>
                {route.title}
            </Text>
        )}
    />
    );

return (

  \<Fragment\>

\<MainContainer\>

            <NavBar title={'Appointment Details'} />
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#113245" barStyle="light-content" />

            <TabView
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                renderScene={renderScene}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
                renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
            />

        </MainContainer>
    </Fragment>
);

}

const ApptPrediagnosisNotes: React.FC = ({ }): JSX.Element =\> {

const \[text1, setText1\] = useState('');

useEffect(() =\>

 {

requestMicrophonePermission();

    Voice.destroy().then(speechInstance.removeAllListeners);

Voice.onSpeechStart = e =\> console.log('onSpeechStart:', e);

   Voice.onSpeechEnd = e =\> {

 console.log('onSpeechEnd:', e);

         setIsListening1(false);

};
speechInstance.onSpeechError = e =\> console.log('onSpeechError:', e);

Voice.onSpeechResults = e =\> {

   const latestSpeechResult = e.value\[0\];

setInput((prevInput1) =\> prevInput1.includes(latestSpeechResult) ?

prevInput1 : ${prevInput1} ${latestSpeechResult}.trim());

setText1((prevText1) =\> prevText1.includes(latestSpeechResult) ?

prevText1 : ${prevText1}    ${latestSpeechResult}.trim());

console.log('the latest is : ' + text1)

};
 return () => {
  Voice.destroy().then(speechInstance.removeAllListeners);
 };

}, \[\]);

const startListening1 = async () =\> {

try {

   setIsListening1(true);

   await Voice.start('en-US');

  catch (e) {

    console.error('Error in startListening:', e);

    setIsListening1(false);

   }

 };

 const stopListening1 = async () =\> {

    try

     {

       await Voice.stop();

 setIsListening1(false);

  }

      catch (e) {

    console.error('Error in stopListening:', e);

 }

};

return(

 \<View\>

 \<TouchableOpacity

           style={{ backgroundColor: colors.chatBackground, paddingHorizontal: 20,

               paddingVertical:    5, alignSelf: 'flex-end', borderRadius: 10,  
              marginBottom: 10   }}  
           onPress={isListening1 ? stopListening1 : startListening1}\>

     \<Text style={{ color: colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: '500' }}\>

     {isListening1 ?    'Stop Listening' : 'Start                    Speaking'}\</Text\>

  \</TouchableOpacity\>

       <TextInput
           multiline
           numberOfLines={15}
           style={{
             height: 100,
             borderColor: '#ccc',
             borderWidth: 0.6,
             marginBottom: 5,
             color: colors.black,
             textAlignVertical: 'top',
             borderRadius: 12,
             padding: 10
            }}
            value={text1}
            id="123"
            onChangeText={newText => handleText(newText)}
            placeholder="Type here.."
            placeholderTextColor={'#ccc'}
        />

    )

}

const PhysicianDiagnosis: React.FC = ({ }): JSX.Element =\> {

useEffect(() =\> {

 requestMicrophonePermission();

 Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);

 Voice.onSpeechStart = e => {
  console.log('onSpeechStart:', e);
 };

 Voice.onSpeechEnd = e => {
  console.log('onSpeechEnd:', e);
  startListening();
 };

 Voice.onSpeechError = e => console.log('onSpeechError:', e);

 Voice.onSpeechResults = e => {
   console.log('onSpeechResults:', e.value);

   const latestSpeechResult = e.value[0];

   setText((prevText) => prevText.includes(latestSpeechResult) ?  
              prevText : `${prevText}  ${latestSpeechResult}`.trim());
   setInput((prevInput) => prevInput.includes(latestSpeechResult) ? 
              prevInput : `${prevInput} ${latestSpeechResult}`.trim());

  console.log('Stored speech:', latestSpeechResult);
};

return () => {
  Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
};

}, \[\]);

const startListening = async () =\> {

 try

  {

   setIsListening2(true);

 await Voice.start('en-US');

  } catch (e) {

  console.error('Error in startListening:', e);

  setIsListening2(false);

 }

};

const stopListening = async () =\> {

  try

 {

 await Voice.stop();

  setIsListening2(false);

}
  catch (e) {

 console.error('Error in stopListening:', e);

   }

   };

   return (

   \<View\>

      \<TouchableOpacity

           style={{ backgroundColor: colors.chatBackground,paddingHorizontal: 20,

                        paddingVertical: 5, borderRadius: 10, }}

           onPress={isListening2 ? stopListening : startListening}\>

         \<Text style={{ color: colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: '500' }}\> 

                    {isListening2 ?  'Stop Listening' : 'Start Speaking'}\</Text\>

      \</TouchableOpacity\>

     \<TextInput

         multiline

         numberOfLines={15}

         style={{

                      height: 100,

                      borderColor: '#ccc',

                      borderWidth: 0.6,

                      marginBottom: 5,

            color: colors.black,

                     textAlignVertical: 'top',

                     borderRadius: 12,

                     padding: 10

}}
         value={text}

         id='abc'

         onChangeText={newText =\> setText(newText)}

         placeholder="Speak or type here"

/>
     \</View\>

)
}
In the above given code im trying to record a voice and convert to text using react-native-voice/voice. Whenever im recording a voice in physician diagnosis it is working properly and when i start recording a voice in the pre diagnosis it is not showing the converted speech to text instead it is showing in the console of the physician diagnosis. Tried by changing the instances, but not working.
Guidance from anyone would be very helpful.
Thank you in advance
